# Error in inputting 7 - 8 command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have been working on a C program which takes in a set of floats and computes the mean/median/mode, variance, and standard deviation for that data set. Currently, if you input between 6 and 7 floats as arguments, those arguments are set as zero. However when using less than six, or more than eight arguments, it does not have the same kind of issue.
Here is an example output of the program with this problem:

```
statistics.exe 20 19 17 17 18 15 20 21
Dataset: 20.000 19.000 17.000 17.000 18.000 15.000 0.000 0.000
```

Here is the code responsible for converting the input into a float array usable by the program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float *dataset;
    int length = argc-1;
    dataset = (float *) malloc(argc);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataset[i] = (float)atof(argv[i+1]);
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to c programming (coming in from C++) so I would love some input as to resolving this matter

Comment: The argument to `malloc` is a number of bytes; since each float is more than one byte, your call should look more like this: `dataset = (float*) malloc(length * sizeof(float));`. Or you can use `calloc`, which takes two arguments: a number of elements, and the size of each element; `dataset = (float*) calloc(length,sizeof(float))l`

Comment: (aside) In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution might look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float *dataset;
    int length = argc - 1;
    char *e, *p;

    dataset = calloc(length,sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        dataset[i] = strtof(p = argv[i + 1],&e);
        if (e == p || *e) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error converting value '%s'\n",p);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

By using `strtof` instead of `atof`, you get some error checking.

Comment: That has definitely done the trick! Thank you so much! I hadn't thought of error checking as usually I keep these small experiment programs to myself but thinking about it that capability sounds incredibly useful. Thanks again